# my SQL query returns 15 rows but while running via hibernate it return 14 rows to the list?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hi I am using the below query to retrieve a list of products.

```
select  qphgr.XPRODHRCHYGRP,qphgr.CPRODHRCHYGRP ,qphgr.CBUSN,qphgr.CSGM
                     from  HPP.PNIGUT pnigu
                     ,HPP.POGSRT pogsr
                     , HQL.QPHGRT qphgr
                     ,HQL.QPRODT qprodt
                         ,HPP.PGPLUT pgplu
                     where  pogsr.CBUSN       = '30'    
                     and pogsr.CSGM       IN ('CBU')
                     and pogsr.CORG    = '25K'
                     and pogsr.CSUPPL      =  '999'
                     and pogsr.CRELT      = 'NIG'
                     and pnigu.DVERSN between pogsr.DFR and pogsr.DTO
                     and pnigu.CBUSN        =  pogsr.CBUSN_REL
                     and pnigu.CSGM         = pogsr.CSGM_REL
                     and pnigu.CORG     = pogsr.CORG_REL
                     and pnigu.CSUPPL        = pogsr.CSUPPL_REL
                     and pnigu.CBUSN = qphgr.CBUSN
                     and pgplu.cmod = qprodt.cmod 
                           and pgplu.CTYP =  qprodt.CTYP 
                           and pgplu.copt =  qprodt.copt 
                           and pgplu.CHECOL =  qprodt.CHECOL
                           and qprodt.CACTIV= 'Y'
                           and qprodt.CBUSN = qphgr.CBUSN
                           and qprodt.CSGM = qphgr.CSGM
                           and qprodt.CPRODHRCHYGRP = qphgr.CPRODHRCHYGRP
                     and pnigu.CORG=pgplu.CORG
                     and pnigu.CSUPPL=qprodt.CSUPPLGEN
                     group by qphgr.XPRODHRCHYGRP,qphgr.CPRODHRCHYGRP,qphgr.CBUSN,qphgr.CSGM,qphgr.NPRNTINGSEQPP
                     order by qphgr.NPRNTINGSEQPP
```

When I run this query in Squirrel it returns 15 rows which is right. But when I'm executing the same query from inside the application (I have used hibernate) it is returning only 14 rows in the return list! How is that possible. What's going wrong?

Comment: Cool naming convention. Is this some kind of code?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HQL query and, maybe, the hibernate config. There's any number of reasons - you could be pointing at the wrong database (dev vs prod), for example... I can't tell based just on a query full of gibberish.

Comment: Can you post the generated sql from the hql query? That can lead to insight when trying to translate a sql query to hql.